# How to send data with post, not get in php?

Tags: php, variables

I have a question concerning variables. Imagine I have a php scripts that shows error messages depending on the the header (www.example.com?error=1). This would show the error message 1.
Now how could I do this without having a variable in the header? I mean using Post instead of Get. How can I "send" a post variable to another script without using a form?

Thanks,
phpheini

PS: The reason why I wanna do is that I dont want people to change the variable in the url (from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on).

Comment: Changing to POST will be in vein if you're looking from a security point of view - it's still trivial to modify the variable client side

Comment: It sounds like you are handling error stats by redirecting instead of outputting a suitable status code and the actual error message directly. If you do that, you won't need to pass the error message via the browser.

Comment: Passing the data via POST isn't going to prevent people from modifying it. You are still getting the data from the browser. You need to rethink your approach completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is you can use html forms to transfer your data using POST method.

PHP just receive the data sent by the browser and the only method to force the post sending is by using forms.

You can use hidden forms spiced with javascript or similar to mimic the link but it is painful to me.

You can also use ajax to transfer the data but there is not a true way to stop the user tampering your datas. It is just a sligthly more difficult. With Firefox and firebug, for example, tampering POSTed variables is a breeze.

Maybe you want to think about changing the loginc behind your application and test the error messages on server side based on real data. 
If you use a link that leads to an error message, maybe, you can avoid to show it, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its not a link, its a file, that contains all the error messages and outputs them. So if there is an error on one of the sites the user will be redirected to the error page. What I could do by the way is not use numbers like 1, 2, 3 but using some md5-strings to not give the user the opportunity to simply change the numbers in the url.

Answer (score 1):

I found this PHP and CURL script from [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/path/to/form");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'foo' => 'foo foo foo',
    'bar' => 'bar bar bar',
    'baz' => 'baz baz baz'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I have not tested this, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You must use cURL to send POST data to other pages. However, this is irrelevant for the kind of thing you want to do. What's the problem with GET? Using either GET or POST, you must always filter user input.